# Firebase is not storing facebook user data in Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication

I have integrated Facebook login in my android app. I can successfully login with facebook but firebase is not storing any of my facebook data i.e email address and also no user is generated in firebase Authentication. Please help me how can I accomplish this. Below is my code

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1D2127"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnfacebook"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1DBF73"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Continue With Facebook"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnJoinNow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnJoinNow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnJoinNow" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button facebook;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      
        facebook = findViewById(R.id.btnfacebook);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email"));


            }
        });
 }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Thanks for Answring

Comment: It looks like you're starting your main activity when you get a 200 response from facebook. But really, you should use this response with FirebaseAuth's signInWithCredentials and THEN show main activitiy

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login